# Single Source Boost Converter?

Tags: mosfet, design, boost

I'm trying to power a 5v microcontroller using a 3.6v rechargeable lithium cell.

My plan is to do this using a boost converter circuit. However, boost converters (at least from my rudimentary understanding) require a signal generator in order to switch the converter's MOSFET on and off, continuously charging and discharging the inductor in the circuit (or something like that).

Would I be able to use my 3.6v cell to power a signal generator circuit to continuously shift the MOSFET?

I'm trying to avoid using another source in order to power the MOSFET, but I will if that's my only option.

Comment: Have you looked at the available boost converter IC's and modules, and their recommended application circuits? I can't recall ever seeing one that needs a second supply.

Comment: Go to TI.com and put your requirements into the WebBench power design tool, and they'll probably give you 3 dozen options, none of which will need a separate supply for the signal generator.

Comment: Boost controllers and boost controller IC's already have intrinsic "signal generators" baked into the design. No external generated signal needed.

Comment: Have a look at how simple boost converters like the [TPS613222A](https://www.ti.com/product/TPS61322) (3 pins) work.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the information about the microcontroller IC (exact type).

Comment: Also, you can use a bjt instead of mosfet. The 3V at battery bottom is more then enough for switching the bjt.

Answer (score 1):

> require a signal generator in order to switch the converter's MOSFET on and off

Usually this signal generator, the control loop, and the MOSFET, are integrated in an IC the size of a discrete mosfet or thereabouts. You definitely don't want to be mucking about with driving mosfets yourself. Just buy a boost converter IC, or even better - a module - that includes IC, inductor, decoupling capacitors, feedback resistors, and a Schottky diode if it is a non-synchronous converter where the diode acts as a 2nd switch.

Synchronous converters have higher efficiency since they use a lower-dissipating MOSFET as the 2nd switch, instead of a diode.

> I'm trying to power a 5v microcontroller using a 3.6v rechargeable lithium cell.

Have you checked that the microcontroller is not specified to work from 3..5V? Many modern 5V microcontrollers have quite wide supply voltage range, often from 2.7V to 5.5V or similar.

> I'm trying to avoid using another source in order to power the MOSFET, but I will if that's my only option.

Pretty much every boost converter out there is powered from a single supply source. Otherwise, what would be the point? There are special applications where a higher auxiliary voltage is available, but those are limited to high power applications usually.